# Swift loop closure function, then completion

Tags: swift, loops, closures

Say I have a function, `closureFunc`, which captures `event`, and I want to make a loop which repeats this function multiple times, and each time appends the captured `event` to an array. How would I do something with the array after the `event`s were appended to it? Here's the general idea, but clearly it doesn't work because `closureFunc` gets called after `doSomething`

```
func doSomething() {
    var events: [Event] = []
    while ... {
        closureFunc(completion: { (event) in 
            events.append(event)
        })
    }

    doSomethingElse(with: events)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it means to be "filled with events"? Is there a maximum number of events the array can hold or something?

Comment: No, I'll fix it.